# Center div with vertical Sliding Content

Tags: html, css

I'm making some page with Vertical Sliding Content. This works well but, i can't center verticaly my content div.

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39kfL/1/

What i need to center the `.content` class vertically from TOP to the beginning of footer content.

Comment: @Jarco hum.. i use 1600x900 resolution and its not centered...as you can see here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/163/divne.jpg/

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Notion

Use the *Centering In The Unknown CSS hack* to vertically center a container with an unknown size; Apply the appropriate rules to the `.item` and the `.container` notated elements to center the contained element within its parent.

In order to pull that off successfully you would also have to compensate for the footer's offset, and set a bottom margin to `.content`. In addition, lose the `top: 17px` declaration on the same element, as it seem to serve no purpose.

#### Code Implementation

```css
.content {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 150px;
    background-color:#aaa;
}

/* ... */


.item:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

#### Demo

- [On jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jjLF/1/)

#### Reference

- [*Centering in the Unknown* by Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)

Comment: can you help me with anoter Centering?.. I don't understand this very well :)

Comment: sure, that's what SO is for. post another question, and comment here with the link if you wish, tho i'm positive others will rush to help you when you do so.

Comment: i make a new one question, with better explanation about my problem, if you can help me... this is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650955/cant-vertically-align-a-div-with-the-technique-of-sticky-footer