# Can't vertically align a div with the technique of Sticky footer

Tags: html, css

I am applying the technique of Styck footer on my site, but my content needs to be aligned both horizontally as vertically in the `#main` But due to the botom `padding-bottom: 180px` when this must be the same size of the footer, my `#main` does not line up vertically. If I take off this padding, and put some value at the `#main` height , this works!, but my footer is not always at the bottom. How should I proceed in this case?

Fiddle with `padding-bottom:180px;`: [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/79aZE/3/)

Fiddle without `padding-bottom:180px;`: [this another link](http://jsfiddle.net/79aZE/4/)

Help please!

Answer (score 1):

first change your HTML structure to

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main" class="block clearfix">
        <div id="wrapper" class="content">
            <p>text</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"> <!-- footer within wrapper -->
       footer content
    </div>
</div>
```

and change in your CSS to

```
#footer { 
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 0; 
    height: 180px;
    clear:both;
    background:#FFCC00;
}
```

Now your footer will always be "attached" to your content.
[Please see the Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/79aZE/4/)